# take urls from lines of a file in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is a line of a file and I want to take only the url after the word **uri** and the url after **smallPictureUrl** to use it later but i can not find a proper way

The asterisks represent text or numbers or both together and the are different in every line who looks like this  so they can not be helpfull, the have not a pattern to take advantage of it

```
{"bigPictureUrl":"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/*-*-*/*.*.*.*/*/*.jpg", 
"timelineCoverPhoto":"{\"focus\":{\"x\":0.5,\"y\":0.49137931034483},\"photo\":{\"__type__

\":{\"name\":\"Photo\"},\"image_lowres\":{\"uri\":\"https://fbcdn-*-*-*.*.*/*-*-*/*.jpg
\",\"width\":180,\"height\":135}}}",
    "subscribeStatus":"IS_SUBSCRIBED","smallPictureUrl":"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/*-*-*/*.*.*.*/*/*.jpg",
```

in something more simple like:

```
{"displayName":"Jim Test","firstName":"*","lastName":"*"}
```

i managed to take the name for example Jim Test after displayName with using the   `re.search('(?<="displayName":")(\w+) (\w+)',line)` but for the other is very complicated if you can give me any direction or advice .

a line is exactly like this

```
{"bigPictureUrl":"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/*.*.*.*/s200x200/*_*_*_*.jpg","timelineCoverPhoto":"{\"focus\":{\"x\":0.5,\"y\":0.40652557319224},\"photo\":{\"__type__\":{\"name\":\"Photo\"},\"image_lowres\":{\"uri\":\"https://fbcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/*_*_*_a.jpg\",\"width\":180,\"height\":120}}}","subscribeStatus":"IS_SUBSCRIBED","smallPictureUrl":"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/*.*.*.*/s100x100/*_*_*_a.jpg","contactId":"**==","contactType":"USER","friendshipStatus":"ARE_FRIENDS","graphApiWriteId":"contact_*:*:*","hugePictureUrl":"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/*.*.*.*/s720x720/*_*_*_*.jpg","profileFbid":"*","isMobilePushable":"NO","lookupKey":null,"name":{"displayName":"* *","firstName":"*","lastName":"*"},"nameSearchTokens":["*","*"],"phones":[],"phoneticName":{"displayName":null,"firstName":null,"lastName":null},"isMemorialized":false,"communicationRank":0.4183731,"canViewerSendGift":false,"canMessage":true}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you not okay with using json, how about this ?

```
>>> print mytext

{"bigPictureUrl":"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/*-*-*/*.*.*.*/*/*.jpg", 
"timelineCoverPhoto":"{"focus":{"x":0.5,"y":0.49137931034483},"photo":{"__type__

":{"name":"Photo"},"image_lowres":{"uri":"https://fbcdn-*-*-*.*.*/*-*-*/*.jpg
","width":180,"height":135}}}",
    "subscribeStatus":"IS_SUBSCRIBED","smallPictureUrl":"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/*-*-*/*.*.*.*/*/*.jpg",

>>> uri = re.findall(r'uri\"\:\"[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', mytext) #gets the uri
>>> smallpicurl = re.findall(r'smallPictureUrl\"\:\"[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', mytext) # gets the smallPictureUrl
>>> ''.join(uri).rstrip()
'https://fbcdn-*-*-*.*.*/*-*-*/*.jpg' # uri
>>> ''.join(smallpicurl).rstrip()
'https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/*-*-*/*.*.*.*/*/*.jpg' # smallPictureUrl
```

Comment: it looks awesome but although it runs in script without error it not prints anything i am sure i am missing something. in the idle the mytext is black but in script the line i write is not black it takes it as string (same color) and some charachters they are not tha same color as the rest string and the are black not like the idle

Comment: On idle, use triple single quotes (''') to initialize the mytext variable. as in mytext = '''your value'''

Comment: on idle i run it with single quotes no problem but i have to do this in 350 lines over a file. i saved one line in a variable as string to test it to see if works and i have no output, i print uri and returns an empty list all this i posted is a single line

Comment: could you paste that one line assignment to the variable from your code..?

Comment: i make a list with all the lines which are needed  by using the append inside a for loop for that lines and then i assign  variable = li[1] for one element of the list to test if it works which is string and i am trying to make it work like you stated above

Comment: it works for smallpicurl but not for uri because there are lines with none value after uri how to manage it??thanks for your help

Comment: you can do someyhing like this ''.join(uri).rstrip() if uri else ''

Comment: for one line it is working fine why in the for loop over all the lines in the file return empty list

Comment: usually it should work; since I don't know the front and back of where you are plugging this code, it's hard to say for me :-|

Comment: i found the issue, when i take somelines from the file with copy paste and asing them to one variable with tripple quotes it works but not when i am calling them from file

Answer (score 2):

The value associated with `timelineCoverPhoto` seems to be stringified JSON, so you could do something admittedly ugly like this:

```
import json 
s = {
        "subscribeStatus": "IS_SUBSCRIBED",
        "bigPictureUrl": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/*-*-*/*.*.*.*/*/*.jpg",
        "timelineCoverPhoto": "{\"focus\":{\"x\":0.5,\"y\":0.49137931034483},\"photo\":{\"__type__\":{\"name\":\"Photo\"},\"image_lowres\":{\"uri\":\"https://fbcdn-*-*-*.*.*/*-*-*/*.jpg \",\"width\":180,\"height\":135}}}",
        "smallPictureUrl": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/*-*-*/*.*.*.*/*/*.jpg" 
    } 

j = json.loads(s.get('timelineCoverPhoto')) 
print "uri:", j.get('photo').get('image_lowres').get('uri')

uri: https://fbcdn-*-*-*.*.*/*-*-*/*.jpg
```

Comment: the line is string is not json and all the file is sting it has been formated with linux command strings

Comment: +1 for using real parser (json) instead of ad hoc regexes. @user1592211: your input data in the question is [JSON that contains embed JSON in it](http://ideone.com/gsPgDu)

Answer (score 2):

```
#See: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls
import re, urllib

GRUBER_URLINTEXT_PAT = re.compile(ur'(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?\xab\xbb\u201c\u201d\u2018\u2019]))')

for line in urllib.urlopen("http://daringfireball.net/misc/2010/07/url-matching-regex-test-data.text"):
print [ mgroups[0] for mgroups in GRUBER_URLINTEXT_PAT.findall(line) ]
```